# Agregar Transaccionalidad a mi codigo Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

espero que tengan buenas tardes , me ire directo al grano con mi pregunta.

Hice este codigo para crear un nuevo registro en la base de datos , encriptar la contraseña, y tambien asignarle inmediatamente un rol , mi pregunta es : ¿Se puede mejorar aun este trozo de codigo , como por ejemplo agregarle transaccionalidad?. Cabe mencionar que la parte la validacion de usuario se la deje todo a SpringSecurity .

```
@PostMapping("/guardar")
    public String guardar(Usuario usuario, Errores errores){

        usuario.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(usuario.getPassword()));


        /**
         * Persistimo el objeto en la base de datos
         **/
        usuarioService.guardarUsuario(usuario);
        /**
         * El Objeto persistido queda en estado de detached con el idUsuario que le asigno la Base de datos.
         **/


        /**
         Creo un nuevo Objeto de tipo Rol , le asigno el nombre y el idUsuario
         * luego atravez de su clase de Servcio la guardo en la base de datos.
         **/

        Rol rol = new Rol();
        rol.setNombre("ROLE_USER");
        rol.setIdUsuario(usuario.getIdUsuario());

        rolService.guardarRol(rol);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Esta es la Interface Dao.

```
package com.administradorUsuario.datos;

import com.administradorUsuario.modelo.Usuario;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UsuarioDao extends JpaRepository<Usuario , Integer>{


    public Usuario findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Y esta es la clase de Servicio.

```
package com.administradorUsuario.servicio;

import com.administradorUsuario.datos.UsuarioDao;
import com.administradorUsuario.modelo.Rol;
import com.administradorUsuario.modelo.Usuario;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Slf4j
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UsuarioServiceImpl implements UsuarioService ,UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioDao usuarioDao;

    @Override
    public List<Usuario> listarUsuarios() {

        return usuarioDao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void guardarUsuario(Usuario usuario) {

        usuarioDao.saveAndFlush(usuario);
    }

    @Override
    public void eliminarUsuario(Usuario usuario) {

        usuarioDao.delete(usuario);
    }

    @Override
    public Usuario encontrarUsuarioPorId(Usuario usuario) {

       return usuarioDao.findById(usuario.getIdUsuario()).orElse(null);
    }



    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Usuario usuario = usuarioDao.findByUsername(username);
        if(usuario==null){

            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        List roles= new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for(Rol rol: usuario.getRoles()){

            roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rol.getNombre()));
        }

        return new User(usuario.getUsername(), usuario.getPassword(),roles);



    }

    @Override
    public Usuario encontrarUsuarioPorUsername(String username) {
         return usuarioDao.findByUsername(username);
    }

}
```

Es mi primera pregunta aca en esta comunidad y si redacte mal mi pregunta una disculpa.
De antemano Gracias.

Comment: Pon los detalles faltantes de tu capa de persistencia para obtener más respuestas.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Adicionalmente puedes mirar [ask]